# Why there exists some finite index normal subgroup of $G_K$ which fixes all elements of $M$?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, group-actions, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G_K$ be an absolute Galois group of algebraic field $K$.
Let $M$ be an finite abelian group.
Let $G$ acts continuously on $M$($G$ with krull topology and $M$ with discrete one), then I want to prove there exists some finite index normal subgroup of  $G_K$ which fixes all elements of $M$.

**I know for all $x∈M$, $stab(x)$ is finite subgroup of $G_K$(I assume this fact here)**, so from here, If I could find normal subgroup which contains union of $stab(x),x∈M$, that is the normal subgroup which I wanted.

But I don't have confident that I can take such normal subgroup.
Another approach are also welcomed, thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you mean $G_K$ instead of $G$? The absolute Galois group of a field always comes with its topology, no need of "algebraic field". Look at $\rho: G_K\to Aut(M)$. No need of continuous action for the existence of the finite index normal subgroup. That the action is continuous implies that the finite index normal subgroup is open (intersection of finitely many open subgroups).